# search text in access database and show msg box with find text

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

can you help me please? I have a two columns in ms access database and I want search text based on inputbox if find text show me msg box with text from input box and text from next column on the same row. is it possible?
first column name: zak
second column name: cisl

thank you

```
Private Sub PictureBox12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox12.Click
        Dim rngVis As String
        Dim VisCell As String
        Dim barcode As String = Nothing
        barcode = InputBox("")
        barcode = InputBox("Naskenujte čárový kód ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||")
        If Len(Trim(barcode)) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

        Dim table As DataTable = SdfDataSet.Tables("vyhl")
        Me.Refresh()
        'Vytvoreni dotazu
        Dim expression As String
        expression = ("[zak] = '" & barcode & "'")
        Dim foundRows() As DataRow


        'vykonani dotazu
        foundRows = table.Select(expression)

        MsgBox("")


    End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to do a bit of research on data access.  You aren't actually retrieving anything from the database with that code.

Comment: You should try to begin with an ODBC connection to your access database.

Comment: I know it, but I dont know how can I get. I have connected database.